# The number of conjugacy classes in a particular set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Suppose we have a set $A = \{\mu \in S_8: |\mu| = 6\} $ and want to determine the number of conjugacy classes in A.

We know in general that that the conjugacy classes of $S_8$ would be the number of partitions of 8. But in this set we consider only the elements in $S_8$ that have order 6.

Comment: What sort of cycle type must an element of order $6$ have?

Comment: Cycle type (3,2), (3,3,2) , (6), (6,1), (6,1,1)?

Comment: Some of those are the same, and you forgot some.

Comment: I just realize that, but I get the idea. The general idea is that we must find all the cycle types who have order 6. From that we can partition 8 into those cycle types which will have LCM 6. And the number of those type of partitions will be the number of conjugacy classes?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for partitions whose LCM (least common multiple) is 6.

> $$\begin{array}{rl} 8 &=6+2 \\ &=6+1+1 \\ &=3+3+2 \\ &=3+2+2+1 \\ &=3+2+1+1+1 \end{array} \quad \text{Or giving representatives:} \quad \begin{array}{l} (1,2,3,4,5,6)(7,8) \\ (1,2,3,4,5,6)(7)(8) \\ (1,2,3)(4,5,6)(7,8) \\ (1,2,3)(4,5)(6,7)(8) \\ (1,2,3)(4,5)(6)(7)(8) \end{array}$$

Comment: So there would 5 conjugacy classes in this case?

Comment: Someone attempted to add more partitions, but they were overlooking the fact that the elements they produced did not have order 6.

Comment: (+1) I, personally, wish I had seen a nice GAP codes below a theoretical approach in the body giving the results, Jack. :)